# Imprimir datos del model hacia un pdf

Tags: django, pdf, django-models

Necesito mostrar datos de la base de datos a un pdf , hasta ahora me genera el pdf pero con datos estaticos que yo le añadí

### VIEWS.PY

```
class PDFprueba(View):

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        datos = {
            'nombre' : 'jose',
            'apellido' : 'florez'
        }
        pdf= render_pdf('pdf/pdf.html',{'datos': datos})

        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type= 'application/pdf')
```

### MODEL.PY

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    edad = models.IntegerField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.EmailField()
    domicilio = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que definir cual serúa tu consulta y hacerla funcionar con el [`queryset` de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/).

Si quieres mostrar todos los datos que tengas insertados en tu tabla (modelo) Persona, sería algo asi:

```
from camino.de.proyecto.models import Persona

...

...
        def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
            datos = []
            for persona in Persona.objects.all():
                datos.append({
                    'nombre' : persona.nombre,
                    'apellido' : persona.apellido,
                })
            pdf = render_pdf('pdf/pdf.html',{'datos': datos})

        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type= 'application/pdf')
```

También vas a tener que modificar tu `render_pdf` para que lea `datos` como una lista.

Comment: mi render_pdf lo tengo compuesto asi :                                                def render_pdf(url_template, contexto=()):

 template = get_template(url_template)
 html = template.render(contexto)
 result = BytesIO()
 pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode('ISO-8859-1')), result)

 if not pdf.err:
  return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(),content_type='application/pdf')

 return None